# DATEDIFF vs DATE to compare dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, datediff

Which way is better:

```
DATE(updated_at) = DATE('2015-03-01 14:34:12')
```

or

```
DATEDIFF(updated_at, '2015-03-01 14:34:12') = 0
```

Comment: Why should one be better than the other?

Answer (score 1):

For performance, you want:

```
(updated_at >= DATE('2015-03-01 14:34:12') and
 updated_at < date_add(DATE('2015-03-01 14:34:12'), interval 1 day)
)
```

This allows MySQL to use an index on `updated_at` for the query.  When you put a column in a function, an index normally cannot be used.

Comment: But if I haven't index for updated_at field? This all options will be equal?

Comment: If you don't have an index on the column, all require a full table scan so all will perform equally badly.